Product Configurator - Unable to use / customise ConfiguratorTextfieldService
We are using text field configurator library in our project. I am trying to use ConfiguratorTextfieldService in my component. But it has some import issue.
constructor(
   private _configuratorTextfieldService: ConfiguratorTextfieldService
) {}

I get the following error.
Module not found: Error: Package path ./textfield/core/facade/configurator-textfield.service is not exported from package /Users/.../node_modules/@spartacus/product-configurator (see exports field in /Users/.../node_modules/@spartacus/product-configurator/package.json)

This is happening because it is not exported in public_api.ts file .
For any component , service to import it needs to exported properly .

Regards
KR

So Can I create a bug in GitHub then?

Give it a try , raise it.
